# Add a PPA with key completely manually, without `add-apt-repository` OR `apt-key adv --recv-keys`

Tags: apt, ppa

I need the exact and complete series of shell incantations for adding a PPA **with key** in the following situation:

- `add-apt-repository` is not installed
- `gnupg` and `gnupg2` are not installed, making it impossible to use `apt-key adv --recv-keys`
- installing those missing tools beforehand is to be avoided at all cost because in the context of docker image building it would require another `apt-get update` run which is slooooowwwwwwww